# Disabled option

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать возможность запрета выбора одинаковых значений в select средством `disabled`?
В данный момент не могу убрать `disabled` у `option` которые были выбраны ранее но были изменены.

```js
$("select").on("change", function() {
  $("select").each(function() {
    $("select option[value='" + $(this).val() + "']").attr("disabled", true);
  });
});
```

```css
select {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option>change</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<select>
  <option>change</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<select>
  <option>change</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Добавил второй вариант. При первом могло немного глючить, если селект закрывается кликом вне селекта)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- При клике на один из `option` убираем `disable` со всех подобных, чтобы можно было выбрать его снова.
- При выборе значения - пробегаемся по всем выбранным `option` и ставим `disabled` для всех `option`, где встречается такое значение

```js
let selectIsOpen = false;
let oldSelectValue = '';

$("select").on("click", function() {
    let choosedValue = $(this).find('option:selected').val();    
    if (selectIsOpen) {            
        if (oldSelectValue === choosedValue)
            $(`option[value=${choosedValue}]`).prop('disabled', true);
        
        selectIsOpen = false;
        return;
    }
      
    $(`option[value=${choosedValue}]`).prop('disabled', false);
    oldSelectValue = choosedValue;
    
    selectIsOpen = true;
});

$("select").on("change", function() {
    let choosedValue = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
    
    $("select option:selected").each(function() {
        $("option[value='" + $(this).val() + "']").prop('disabled', true);
    });
});
```

```css
select {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option>change</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<select>
  <option>change</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<select>
  <option>change</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

---

Менее глючный вариант (если селект закрывается не кликом, а ещё и при клике вне области селекта)

```js
let selectIsOpen = false;
let oldSelectValue = '';

const disableOptionsOnClose = (selectedOption) => {
    $("select option:selected").each(function() {
        $("option[value='" + $(selectedOption).val() + "']").prop('disabled', true);
    });
    
    resetFlagsAndData();
}

const resetFlagsAndData = () => {
    selectIsOpen = false;
    oldSelectValue = '';
}

$("select").on("click", function() {
    let choosedValue = $(this).find('option:selected').val();    
    
    if (selectIsOpen) {     
        disableOptionsOnClose($(this));
        return;
    }
  
    $(`option[value=${choosedValue}]`).prop('disabled', false);    
    oldSelectValue = choosedValue;    
    selectIsOpen = true;
});

$("select").on("blur", function() {
    disableOptionsOnClose($(this));
});
```

```css
select {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option>change</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<select>
  <option>change</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<select>
  <option>change</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```